# Portable Dropbox (FileSync)?

Tags: synchronization, dropbox

Is there a portable version of Dropbox that I can load on to a USB Key?

I need to sync my files between my home desktop, dormitory laptop and on occasion a computer in my university lab.

I need it to load from a USB Key as I cannot install Dropbox on the computer in my univeristy lab.

I would like to avoid manually copying files from my university lab computer to a USB Key and then to my laptop. This process is too laborious and prone to errors (i.e. copying out of date files etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [DropboxPortable](http://dropportable.ho.am/#english-home)

**Features**

- Provides the newest dropbox version available
- Keeps dropbox up to date
- Makes it fully portable -> you do not have to install it on every pc you use, just copy the entire directory and start the application
- You can put your dropbox on your USB-Stick and have it with you all the time
- You can select which folders should be synchronized to your folder (Selective Sync)
- You can maintain multiple dropbox accounts on the same computer/user account
  -You can use your dropbox everywhere, also without administrator privileges
- If a new version is released, the old version will pop up a notification window asking you whether you want to update it or not.

**Special features**

- SyncAndGo - Let Dropbox sync all files and close it afterwards
- User Applications - Run applications before and after the execution of Dropbox
- Connection Profiles - Set up different connection settings

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I will test this in my class tomorrow! Thanks man!